# Displaying a 3d array using a single loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying soo hard to display a 3d array using a single loop but unable to do so..   Please help me out!!

I trieed printing a 2d array with a single loop by giving the row index=i\col and column=i%col and it worked so i also wanted to try the 3d array but cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: Just repeat the same technique. If you have `dim1`, `dim2` and `dim3` and you want `i`, `j` and `k` corresponding to those dimensions. Then `i = index/(dim2*dim3);` and `index2 = index%(dim2*dim3);`, and then `j = index2/dim3;` and `k = index2%dim3;`.